# WeakReference to garbage collect Remote Objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jgroups

I am playing around with JGroups as a distributed system. I want to create objects on a remote JVM and use them as if they were created locally. Therefore I am using a java.lang.reflect.Proxy to wrap the RPC calls. This is a much like RMI behavior. This works very well.

But now I want to garbage collect the remote object if the client interface/proxy is no longer in use. So I thought I can get this working by using a WeakReference but I never fall into the GC cycle. What am I missing?

```
public class RMILikeWrapper {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService garbageCollector = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private final Map remoteObjects = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    private final Map<WeakReference, IdPointer> grabageTracker = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ReferenceQueue rq = new ReferenceQueue();
    private final RpcDispatcher rpcDispatcher;
    private final long callTimeout = 10000L;

    private class IdPointer {
        public final Address address;
        public final String id;

        public IdPointer(Address address, String id) {
            this.address = address;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "IdPointer{" + "address=" + address + ", id='" + id + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }

    public RMILikeWrapper(Channel channel) {
        this.rpcDispatcher = new RpcDispatcher(channel, null, null, this);

        // enable garbage collecting
        garbageCollector.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("my GC ");

                Reference<?> ref;  //this should be our weak reference
                while((ref = rq.poll()) != null) {
                    // remove weak reference from the map
                    IdPointer garbage = grabageTracker.remove(ref);

                    System.out.println("found expired weak references: " + garbage);
                    // now we need to destroy the remote object too
                    try {
                        rpcDispatcher.callRemoteMethod(garbage.address, "purge", new Object[]{garbage.id},
                                new Class[]{String.class}, new RequestOptions(ResponseMode.GET_FIRST, callTimeout));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        },0,10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public <T>T createRemoteObject(Class<T> proxyInterface, Address targetNode, Class c, Object[] args, Class[] argTypes) {
        try {
            Object[] remoteArgs = new Object[4];
            remoteArgs[0] = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            remoteArgs[1] = c;
            remoteArgs[2] = args;
            remoteArgs[3] = argTypes;

            rpcDispatcher.callRemoteMethod(targetNode, "addObject", remoteArgs,
                    new Class[]{String.class, Class.class, Object[].class, Class[].class},
                    new RequestOptions(ResponseMode.GET_FIRST, callTimeout));

            // now get in interface stub for this object
            return getRemoteObject(targetNode, remoteArgs[0].toString(), proxyInterface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Operation triggerd by RPC
    public void addObject(String id, Class c, Object[] args, Class[] parameterTypes) throws Exception {
        remoteObjects.put(id, c.getConstructor(parameterTypes).newInstance(args));
    }

    // Operation triggerd by RPC
    public Object invoke(String id, String methodName, Object[] args, Class[] argTypes) throws Exception {
        Object ro = remoteObjects.get(id);
        return ro.getClass().getMethod(methodName, argTypes).invoke(ro, args);
    }

    // Operation triggerd by RPC
    public void purge(String id) {
        System.out.println("garbage collecting: " + id);

        //return remoteObjects.remove(id) != null;
        remoteObjects.remove(id);
    }

    public <T>T getRemoteObject(final Address nodeAdress, final String id, final Class<T> clazz) {
        if (!clazz.isInterface()) throw new RuntimeException("Class has to be an interface!");

        InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke (Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                Object[] remoteArgs = new Object[4];
                remoteArgs[0] = id;
                remoteArgs[1] = method.getName();
                remoteArgs[2] = args;
                remoteArgs[3] = method.getParameterTypes();

                // remote call
                return rpcDispatcher.callRemoteMethod(nodeAdress, "invoke",
                        remoteArgs, new Class[]{String.class, String.class, Object[].class, Class[].class},
                        new RequestOptions(ResponseMode.GET_FIRST, callTimeout));
            }
        };

        T result = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                clazz.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{clazz},
                handler);

        // use weak pointers to the proxy object here and if one is garbage collected, purge the remote object as well
        WeakReference<T> weakReference = new WeakReference<>(result, rq);
        grabageTracker.put(weakReference, new IdPointer(nodeAdress, id));

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Channel channel = new JChannel();
        channel.connect("test-cluster");

        List<Address> members = channel.getView().getMembers();
        RMILikeWrapper w = new RMILikeWrapper(channel);

        if (members.size() > 1) {
            System.out.println("send to " + members.get(0));
            FooInterface remoteObject = w.createRemoteObject(FooInterface.class, members.get(0), FooImpl.class, null, null);
            System.out.println(remoteObject.doSomething("Harr harr harr"));
            remoteObject = null;
        }

        System.out.println(channel.getView().getMembers());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to reinvent RMI's Distibuted Garbage Collection, there's no need. It already exists and already works. All you have to do is release the remote stub.

Comment: But JGroups is using a custom protocoll for RPC it is not RMI because JGroups is a dynamic clustering solution not a classic client server architecture like RMI is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following methods you could identify how GC behaves on weak references.
Option 1:

-verbose:gc

This argument record GC behaviour whenever GC kicks into picture. You could take the log file when you want to check did GC gets into action, It could be checked from the GC logs. For Interactive GC analysis try the log with http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/gcmv/

Option 2 :

Collect Heap dump and user event and load it in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/memoryanalyzer/

Write OQL(Object Query language) on OQL section
select *  from package(s).classname
and click on ! on the tool bar 
It will give list of objects of that type
Right click on the objects -> Path to GC roots -> Exclude soft/weak/Phantom references 
 If suspect object does not have any strong reference then it will show NULL  else
you will get information on who is holding the strong references on the suspected object.